# moment.js concatenate date and time

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, momentjs

I have four fields in a form, some containing an initial date and the end date (dd / mm / yyyy) and the others contain the start time and the end time (hh: ss).

The value of these fields I use to get the date and time with moment.js such as this:

```
initialdate = moment( $('input#start_date').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
start_time = moment( $('input#start_time').val(), 'HH:mm');
enddate = moment( $('input#enddate').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
end_time = moment( $('input#end_time').val(), 'HH:mm');
```

What I intend is to then get the difference in seconds between the two dates, concatenating the starting date and time and the ending date and time. I have tried to do this, but to no avail:

```
start = initialdate + start_time;
end = enddate + end_time;
tracker = moment.duration( end.diff(start) ).asSeconds();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The fail is trying on concatenate the values, test with something like this:

```
let initialdate = '2016-10-01';
let start_time = '19:04:10';
let enddate = '2016-10-01';
let end_time = '19:04:20';

let datetimeA = moment(initialdate + " " + start_time);
let datetimeB = moment(enddate + " " + end_time);

console.log(datetimeA.format());
console.log(datetimeB.format());

let datetimeC = datetimeB.diff(datetimeA, 'seconds');

console.log(datetimeC);
```

Comment: `initialdate + start_date` fails because they are both Moment objects at that point.

Answer (score 38):

Concatenate the date and time strings and parse them as one, e.g.

```js
var date = '23/02/2017';
var time = '15:42';

var dateTime = moment(date + ' ' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

console.log(dateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 24):

**[2021] Most elegant solution is:**

```
/* `date` and `time` are instances of Moment */

    date = date.set({
          hour: time.get('hour'),
          minute: time.get('minute'),
          second: 0,
          millisecond: 0,
        });
```

Comment: what about AM or PM?

Comment: This solution confirmed working with with am/pm times.

Answer (score 10):

A much cleaner solution IMO is to use moment's `hour` and `minute` getters and setters.

```
let a = moment()
let b = moment().add(3, 'hour').add(37, 'minute') //b is the time portion
a.hour(b.hour()).minute(b.minute())
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this function

```
function getCombinedDateObject(date, time) {
let calculatedDateString = '';
if (date && time) {
  let utcDate = moment.utc(date);
  let utcTime = moment.utc(time);
  calculatedDateString = moment(`${utcDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} ${utcTime.format("HH:mm:ss z")}`);
}
let finalDateTime = new Date(calculatedDateString);
if (isNaN(finalDateTime.getTime()))
  return null;
else
  return finalDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is simple,
I just change the time of date as following:

```
const date = new Date(myDate)
const time = new Date(myTime)
date.setHours(time.getHours())
date.setMinutes(time.getMinutes())
```