# Use momentjs to take two datetime values, grab the date from the first, and time from the second

Tags: momentjs

Like the title says, I have two moment values. From the first I need to grab the date (will be a future date) and from the second value I need to grab the time.  I looked at [this here about connecting two values, but didnt exaclty work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404507/moment-js-concatenate-date-and-time)

So the first moment() returns `Thu Jun 28 2021 15:45:50 GMT-0400` of which i need the dayte

The second moment() returns `Thu Jun 24 2021 16:42:50 GMT-0400` of which i need the time

What is best way to put the two moment values together ? so i would get `Thu Jun 28 2021 16:42:50 GMT-0400`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is with `moment().set()`

like this `moment(myDate).set('hour', moment(myTime).format('HH')).set('minute', moment(time).format('mm'));`