# Concatenate moment datetime objects into one using date from one and time from another in JavaScript (React)

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have two Moment DateTime objects, called 'date' and 'time' respectively, each receiving their values from input fields from the Ant Design library. I want to take the date from one and the time from another, then combine them onto a single DateTime object.

I've tried things like the below:

```
moment(date?.get('year') + '-' + date?.get('month') + '-' + date?.get('date') + 'T' + time?.get('hour') + ':' + time?.get('minute')+':00.000Z') //this does not result in a DateTime object

moment(date?.toDate(), time.toTime()) //this was a bit of an experiment. toDate works, but toTime not
```

I have found similar questions, but in these cases, they are using string data instead of a DateTime object, e.g.:

[moment.js concatenate date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404507/moment-js-concatenate-date-and-time)

I could of course follow this example and generate a string, which is essentially similar what I was doing in my examples above.

I feel like I might be overcomplicating things, however. Is there a simple way to do this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `date` and `time` are `Moment` objects, you can just set hour and minute of `date` with the values of `time`. Then, `toDate()` gives you Javascript DateTime object. I can't think of a shorter way.

```js
const date = moment("2021-10-19", "YYYY-MM-DD"); // date parts, be careful about timezone
const time = moment("10:00", "HH-mm"); // time parts, may be extended with seconds, milliseconds

// Assuming that date or time can be null or undefined below

console.log(date?.format());
console.log(time?.format());

// Let's add hour and minute of time to date

date?.hour(time ? time.hours() : date.hours()).minute(time ? time.minutes() : date.minutes());

console.log(date?.format()); // time of date is set

console.log(date?.toDate()); // Javascript DateTime object
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, this works great. I've just added setting the seconds to 0 as well, otherwise it keeps the seconds from the original 'date' object: date?.hour(time ? time.hours() : date.hours()).minute(time ? time.minutes() : date.minutes()).seconds(0);